# Problems deploying to github project pages

Tags: deployment, github, blogs, jekyll, assets

Sorry if maybe I'm asking something very basic. I'm having some problems when deploying this [repository](https://github.com/mipumh/blog) which is not under a User or Organization Github account. When I deploy to localhost I don't have any problems at all and the blog theme runs perfectly. But this is not the case when I deploy to this Project page. You can see the publication result [here](http://mip.umh.es/blog/).

Any tips?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by deploy - pushing the repo? And what is the specific error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html page you have given the path to your css, js and images from the site root eg: `/images/logo.png`, but your files are inside the blog folder. Change the paths in your index.html page to document-relative paths like this: `images/logo.png`.

Answer (score 1):

Saravana is right about the inconsistency of your URLs, however I would suggest the following solution which I believe is a bit cleaner.

There is a `baseurl` variable that can be set in your `_config.yml` file. This can then be referenced in your layouts and other files with the `{{ site.baseurl }}` liquid templating syntax.

You can then do something like the following to get consistency across development and deployment:

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/images/logo.png">
```

The other benefit here is that if for some reason you need to update the base URL, you can do it in one place (the `_config.yml`) rather than having to go through and modify every URL in your site.

Read more about [Jekyll configuration here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).